# import list to excel

Tags: python, list, import, export-to-excel

I want to import the python list to excel. My example code is:

```
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = 1
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

list1 =("a","b","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c")

ws.Range("B1:B10").Value = list1
```

How I have to change the list1 type to use the code ws.Range("B1:B10").Value = list1? What kind of list can use in excel file?

Comment: List1 is a tuple, you should use square brackets for a list: `list1 =["a", "b" ... "c"]`. Not sure if this matters. You could loop or use the `xlwt` library to solve this.

Comment: thanks @EdSmith, actually I want my list become like that `list1 =(("a",),("b",),("c",),("c",),("c",),("c",).....)` It will be easy to write to excel. And I do not want to use other library except win32. That is the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014261/python-excel-writing-to-multiple-cells-takes-time) may do what you need by wrapping your range statement in a function like:

```
def writeLinesToExcel(ws,lines): 
    ws.Range("A1:"+chr(len(lines)+96).upper()+str(len(lines[0]))).Value=lines
```

Then you can call
`writeLineToExcel(ws,list1)`. You can also use things like [["a"],["b"]] apparently... Based on your question, I'm not sure this appears to be working for you. If your data is simple enough, you could just use a loop,

```
def writeRowsToExcel(ws,col,rows): 

    for i,l in enumerate(rows):
        ws.Cells(col,i)= l
```

then call `writeRowsToExcel(ws, col, rows)`. Other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478946/writing-array-to-excel-in-python-with-win32com)  suggest this will be slow and to use other libraries like `xlwt`.

Comment: thanks @Ed Smith, Actually, I do not want to create a loop to write data to excel file because it will be slow if my data is big. So I try another method, I will create a tuple for mys list first and then write to excel file
`for i in list:`

     `new_list.append((i,))` 

 `ws.Range(B1,B10) = new_list `
Do you think is it ok?

Comment: I don't have a windows machine to test, it looks like the syntax you use should work based on other posts -- do you have the latest version of win32com? Sorry, realised the link above us wrong, I've updated.

Comment: I download it from the link [win32com link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/)